# Getting a 401 error when trying to create a new post

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a post using an app built in react native but everytime I try creating it gives me a 401 error after I have already logged in. I assume it isn't getting a token from AsyncStorage. I need helping.

This is the ItemContext where the functionality for creating a post-

```
import createDataContext from "./createDataContext";
import sellerApi from "../api/seller";
import { navigate } from "../navigationRef";

const itemReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "fetch_items":
      return action.payload;
    case "create_item":
      return { errorMessage: "", item: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const fetchItems = dispatch => async () => {
  const response = await sellerApi.get("/api/items");
  console.log(response.data);
  dispatch({ type: "fetch_items", payload: response.data });
};

const createItem = dispatch => async (
  title,
  category,
  detail,
  condition,
  price
) => {
  try {
    const response = await sellerApi.post("/api/items", {
      title,
      category,
      detail,
      condition,
      price
    });
    //this is the other place the error might be happening i need this to save in the phone local storage
    console.log(response.data);
    dispatch({ type: "create_item", payload: response.data });

    navigate("Home");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

export const { Provider, Context } = createDataContext(
  itemReducer,
  { createItem, fetchItems },
  []
);
```

this is the AuthContext where the signin and signup functionality is located and the AsyncStorage is used. Let me know if you guys need to see the node function for Auth.

```
import createDataContext from "./createDataContext";
import sellerApi from "../api/seller";
import { navigate } from "../navigationRef";

const authReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "add_error":
      return { ...state, errorMessage: action.payload };
    case "signup":
      return { errorMessage: "", token: action.payload };
    case "signin":
      return { errorMessage: "", token: action.payload };
    case "fetch_user":
      return action.payload;
    case "clear_error_message":
      return { ...state, errorMessage: "" };
    case "signout":
      return { token: null, errorMessage: "" };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const tryLocalSignin = dispatch => async () => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
  if (token) {
    dispatch({ type: "signin", payload: token });
    navigate("Home");
  } else {
    navigate("loginFlow");
  }
};

const clearErrorMessage = dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: "clear_error_message" });
};

const signup = dispatch => async ({ name, phone, email, password }) => {
  try {
    const response = await sellerApi.post("/api/users", {
      name,
      phone,
      email,
      password
    });
    //this is the other place the error might be happening i need this to save in the phone local storage
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("token", response.data);
    console.log(response.data);
    dispatch({ type: "signup", payload: response.data.token });

    navigate("Home");
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({ type: "add_error", payload: "FAIL" });
  }
};

const signin = dispatch => async ({ email, password }) => {
  try {
    const response = await sellerApi.post("/api/auth", {
      email,
      password
    });
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("token", response.data);
    console.log(response.data);
    dispatch({ type: "signin", payload: response.data.token });

    navigate("Home");
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({ type: "add_error", payload: "FAIL" });
  } 
}; 

// const fetchUser = dispatch => async () => {
//   const response = await sellerApi.get("/auth");
//   dispatch({ type: "fetch_user", payload: response.data });
// };

//need to get the users info to display it in the accountScreen

const signout = dispatch => async () => {
  await AsyncStorage.removeItem("token");
  dispatch({ type: "signout" });
  navigate("loginFlow");
};

export const { Provider, Context } = createDataContext(
  authReducer,
  { signup, signin, signout, tryLocalSignin },
  { token: null, errorMessage: "" }
);
```

This is the backend for the Auth function that makes sure the user is logged in before begin able to send a post request----

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const config = require("config");


module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  const token = req.header("x-auth-token");
  if (!token) return res.status(401).send("Access denied");

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get("jwtPrivateKey"));
    req.user = decoded;
    next();
  } catch (ex) {
    res.status(400).send("Invalid token.");
  }
}
```

this is where the post request for when you signup and login is pretty much similar-

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validate(req.body);
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (user) return res.status(400).send("User already registered.");

  user = new User(_.pick(req.body, "name", "phone", "email", "password"));
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);

  await user.save();

  const token = user.generateAuthToken();
  res.header("x-auth-token", token).send(token);
});
```

PLEASE HELP

Comment: how have you imported asyncStorage? please share that too

Comment: the AuthContext page is the only place I have used AsyncStorage

Comment: no , i mean like import Asynstorage from 'react-native' have you done like this>

Comment: on the top of AuthContext I imported it like this: import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";

Comment: You don't send the token in your POST request, I think you need to read token from AsynStorage and send it in the header where your api expects.

Answer (score 0):

Importing  Async storage like this `import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';` has been deprecated. You can check here [async storage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage) .

Thats why i suppose the AsyncStorage is not working, try downloading this [rn-community-async-storage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage)  .  package first and then import AsyncStorage like

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: I also added the backend for the setting the x-auth-token